# Convert byte array to a string - - With Performace Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

```
Bitmap foto = b.getBitmap();

byte[] bytes = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
foto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ba);
foto.recycle();
foto = null;

bytes = ba.toByteArray();

String bBytes = Arrays.toString(bytes);
```

I'd like this method to return a String of the Byte values. For example, it would be : `"12,23,34 ...."`.

Comment: So you expect folks to first __translate__ your question?

Comment: I've tried to fix what I've understood in his question.

Comment: Which method do you mean by this method?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = {1,2,3,12};
        String bBytes = Arrays.toString(bytes);
        bBytes = bBytes.replaceAll(" ", "");
        bBytes = bBytes.replaceAll("\\[", "");
        bBytes = bBytes.replaceAll("\\]", "");
        System.out.println(bBytes);     
    }

}
```

Comment: when small bitmap, works perfect, but when and large bitmap, this conversion takes too long, already thought about doing that with NDK, maybe the performace is excellent.

The problem is this line:
String bBytes = Arrays.toString(bytes);

Comment: First time you mention about performance issues. Post another question, I would suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385728/convert-byte-array-to-a-string-with-performace-android